Contour plots from points
I have data in the form of longitude, latitude, and value. they are all list.
how can I plot contour plot for such data?
The example in the documentation converts longitude and latitude to meshgrid, but I don't have the values at all the meshgrid points.
Is there an easy way to plot contour from points?

Short answer is not really possible and the results of trying may be unsatisfactory. You first have to choose a projection of the sphere onto a rectangular grid and then interpolate your data onto that mesh grid that the contouring routine wants to see. If you make the simplifying assumption that your values represent a smoothly changing variable then diffusing the known values out across the grid might be a reasonable way to proceed. You only have  bunch of random spot heights what actually happens in between them is anybody's guess unless you have a physical model.

I agree with @MartinBrown other than the suggestion to interpolate through diffusion. There are much better and faster methods. The simplest one is probably inverse distance weighting. Kriging/Gaussian processes is also a data and time efficient method.

For working with non-gridded data, there is plt.tricontour(longitudes, latitudes, values). Internally, this creates a triangulation and finds the contour lines inside each little triangle. See this example

Thanks Martin, Paul, and Johan for your response.
